# mRemoteNG - how to change the password

Tags: mremoteng

In mRemoteNG, how can you change the password of an already protected password file?

There is no option for it in '*Tools > Options*' as one might expect, and there is no item for it in the '*Help*' menu.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:
You need to disable password protection, and then enable it again

Full answer:
After you already open the password file, click on the '*Connections*' section:
[image]

Then, in the config section, choose the option '*Password Protect*', and choose '*No*'.

Afterwards, choose '*Yes*' at the same location, and you will be prompted for the new password:
[image]

Remember to **save the connection file** when you are done!